# read the data from XML Structure using c#

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I store the xml file in one **string object** like,I stored the xml structure in **local variable string abcd** in c#.

```
 <structure>
    <a>Test Name</a>
    <e>test address</e>
    <c>
       <c1>yyyy<c1>
       <c2>xxxx</c2>
    </c>
    </structure>
```

How to read(parse) this xml string using c# and store the tag a,and tag c1 ,tag c2 values in local variable using c#.

i tried like

```
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.LoadXml(abcd);

        XmlElement element = (XmlElement)xmldoc.GetElementById("a");
```

but i get null value.how to read the values from xml structure and stored in local variable using c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq2Xml is much easier to use.

```
var xElem = XElement.Parse(abcd);
var a = xElem.Element("a").Value;
var c = xElem.Element("c").Element("c1").Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ to XML:

```
 var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

 var a = xDoc.Descendants("a").First().Value;
 var c1 = xDoc.Descendants("c1").First().Value;
 var c2 = xDoc.Descendants("c2").First().Value;
```

Comment: from string not from XML file

Comment: still a yummy answer though

Answer (score 0):

```
string test = " <structure><a>Test Name</a><e>test address</e><c><c1>yyyy</c1><c2>xxxx</c2></c></structure>";

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

        dataSet.ReadXml(new StringReader(test));
        DataTable dt11 = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt12 = new DataTable();
        //return single table inside of dataset
        if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 1)
        {
            dt11 = dataSet.Tables[0];
            dt12 = dataSet.Tables[1];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at LINQ to XML yet? If not, see the reference at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Very close! Change it to this:

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument(); 
xmldoc.LoadXml(abcd); 

XmlElement element = xmldoc.Root.Element("a").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you are trying to access every different tag in the xml document so you should use `GetElementsByTagName` instead of `GetElementById`. This returns a `XmlNodeList` object containing all nodes with that tag name and you can get the First as `NodeList.Item(0).InnerXml;`

Answer (score -1):

To use the XDocument class in the accepted answer, you need to add:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

AND

*From solution explorer, locate "references"
*right click "Add reference"
*search Assembles (Ctrl E) for XML
*select the xml.ling item
*click the check box that appears on the left
*choose okay