# Read xml descendants collection from xml string

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

```
<feed xml:base="http://test.table.core.windows.net/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <id>http://test.table.core.windows.net/Colors</id>
  <title type="text">Colors</title>

  <link rel="self" title="Colors" href="Colors" />
 <entry m:etag="W/"datetime'2015-08-27T10%3A59%3A47.8592342Z'"">    
    <category term="test.Colors" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <link rel="edit" title="Colors" href="Colors(PartitionKey='AAA',RowKey='0001')" />
    <title />
    <updated>2015-08-30T03:39:10Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:PartitionKey>AAA</d:PartitionKey>
        <d:RowKey>0001</d:RowKey>        
        <d:ColorName>Blue</d:ColorName>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
 <entry m:etag="W/"datetime'2015-08-27T10%3A59%3A47.8592341Z'"">   
    <category term="test.Colors" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <link rel="edit" title="Colors" href="Colors(PartitionKey='AAA',RowKey='1002')" />
    <title />

    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:PartitionKey>AAA</d:PartitionKey>
        <d:RowKey>1002</d:RowKey>
       <d:ColorName>Blue</d:ColorName>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry m:etag="W/"datetime'2015-08-27T10%3A59%3A47.8592343Z'"">    
    <category term="test.Colors" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <link rel="edit" title="Colors" href="Colors(PartitionKey='AAZ',RowKey='0111')" />
    <title />

    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:PartitionKey>AAZ</d:PartitionKey>
        <d:RowKey>0111</d:RowKey>        
        <d:ColorName>Blue</d:ColorName>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

How can I read "m:properties" descendants using C# or LINQ. This xml string is stored in variable of type XElement

Comment: This question is linked with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292233/reading-child-nodes-from-xml-string-using-c-linq (that resloved)

Comment: I don't get the difference between this and the linked question. Is it that you have multiple `m:properties` elements here?

Comment: Your previous solution is working fine in case of single m:properties element. But in this xml string(question) there are multiple m:properties elements

Comment: Why the previous solution wouldn't work with multiple `m:properties`? The code is returning list already. As long as `myxelement` contains all the `m:properties`, it should work as well for this case. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you are right. Previous solution is also working with multiple m:preperties. My mistake